# FTP MGET - is there a limit to the how many files can be specified?

Tags: ftp, mget

I am using MGET to get a list of specific files (300 or so) where each filename is specifically listed.

It looks like the string of files is being split (and thus, incomplete) and the transfer fails because it can not find the file for the broken filenames.

```
OPEN ***************
220 ftp-out FTP server ready.
User (***************): 
331 Password required for *****.

230 User ***** logged in.  Access restrictions apply.
ftp> TYPE binary
200 Type set to I.
ftp> Interactive mode Off .

ftp> PROMPT off
CD incoming
250 CWD command successful.
ftp> Local directory now C:\csrkb\etl\files\incoming\TASK0460\txt.

ftp> LCD C:\csrkb\etl\files\incoming\TASK0460\txt
MGET WKEXTR01.RPT.0510084359 WKEXTR01.RPT.0517092009 WKEXTR01.RPT.0524093522 WKEXTR01.RPT.0531074955 WKEXTR01.RPT.0601174047 detextro1.rpt.05020232 detextro1.rpt.05020553 detextro1.rpt.05020833 detextro1.rpt.05020940 detextro1.rpt.05021039 detextro1.rpt.05021129 detextro1.rpt.05021229 detextro1.rpt.05021323 detextro1.rpt.05021425 detextro1.rpt.05021531 detextro1.rpt.05021633 detextro1.rpt.05021742 detextro1.rpt.05021850 detextro1.rpt.05022058 detextro1.rpt.05022331 detextro1.rpt.05030018 detextro1.rpt.05030251 detextro1.rpt.05030556 detextro1.rpt.05030829 detextro1.rpt.05030925 detextro1.rpt.05031022 detextro1.rpt.05031125 detextro1.rpt.05031223 detextro1.rpt.05031324 detextro1.rpt.05031425 detextro1.rpt.05031529 detextro1.rpt.05031626 detextro1.rpt.05031726 detextro1.rpt.05031825 detextro1.rpt.05032033 detextro1.rpt.05032335 detextro1.rpt.05040025 detextro1.rpt.05040305 detextro1.rpt.05040606 detextro1.rpt.05040858 detextro1.rpt.05040952 detextro1.rpt.05041053 detextro1.rpt.05041142 detextro1.rpt.05041243 detextro1.rpt.05041329 detextro1.rpt.05041429 detextro1.rpt.05041548 detextro1.rpt.05041649 detextro1.rpt.05041744 detextro1.rpt.05041841 detextro1.rpt.05042049 detextro1.rpt.05042339 detextro1.rpt.05050032 detextro1.rpt.05050317 detextro1.rpt.05050609 detextro1.rpt.05050908 detextro1.rpt.05051015 detextro1.rpt.05051105 detextro1.rpt.05051157 detextro1.rpt.05051239 detextro1.rpt.05051339 detextro1.rpt.05051435 detextro1.rpt.05051542 detextro1.rpt.05051644 detextro1.rpt.05051744 detextro1.rpt.05051843 detextro1.rpt.05052055 detextro1.rpt.05052341 detextro1.rpt.05060032 detextro1.rpt.05060300 detextro1.rpt.05060612 detextro1.rpt.05060910 detextro1.rpt.05060959 detextro1.rpt.05061105 detextro1.rpt.05061158 detextro1.rpt.05061255 detextro1.rpt.05061339 detextro1.rpt.05061443 detextro1.rpt.05061544 detextro1.rpt.05061650 detextro1.rpt.05061746 detextro1.rpt.05061845 detextro1.rpt.05062058 detextro1.rpt.05062340 detextro1.rpt.05070052 detextro1.rpt.05070355 detextro1.
detextro1.: No such file or directory.

200 Type set to I.
Cannot find list of remote files.

ftp> Invalid command.

ftp> rpt.05070606 detextro1.rpt.05070859 detextro1.rpt.05070950 detextro1.rpt.05071050 detextro1.rpt.05071148 detextro1.rpt.05071234 detextro1.rpt.05071327 detextro1.rpt.05071426 detextro1.rpt.05071555 detextro1.rpt.05071638 detextro1.rpt.05071728 detextro1.rpt.05071828 detextro1.rpt.05072039 detextro1.rpt.05072217 detextro1.rpt.05080920 detextro1.rpt.05081022 detextro1.rpt.05081130 detextro1.rpt.05081215 detextro1.rpt.05081309 detextro1.rpt.05081409 detextro1.rpt.05081508 detextro1.rpt.05081609 detextro1.rpt.05081708 detextro1.rpt.05081811 detextro1.rpt.05082010 detextro1.rpt.05082322 detextro1.rpt.05090016 detextro1.rpt.05090234 detextro1.rpt.05090552 detextro1.rpt.05090833 detextro1.rpt.05090943 detextro1.rpt.05091034 detextro1.rpt.05091129 detextro1.rpt.05091229 detextro1.rpt.05091324 detextro1.rpt.05091422 detextro1.rpt.05091530 detextro1.rpt.05091642 detextro1.rpt.05091737 detextro1.rpt.05091849 detextro1.rpt.05092051 detextro1.rpt.05092332 detextro1.rpt.05100016 detextro1.rpt.05100257 detextro1.rpt.05100558 detextro1.rpt.05100830 detextro1.rpt.05100926 detextro1.rpt.05101028 detextro1.rpt.05101129 detextro1.rpt.05101223 detextro1.rpt.05101322 detextro1.rpt.05101424 detextro1.rpt.05101522 detextro1.rpt.05101624 detextro1.rpt.05101725 detextro1.rpt.05101819 detextro1.rpt.05102037 detextro1.rpt.05102332 detextro1.rpt.05110023 detextro1.rpt.05110259 detextro1.rpt.05110603 detextro1.rpt.05110907 detextro1.rpt.05111003 detextro1.rpt.05111103 detextro1.rpt.05111150 detextro1.rpt.05111236 detextro1.rpt.05111332 detextro1.rpt.05111435 detextro1.rpt.05111546 detextro1.rpt.05111639 detextro1.rpt.05111740 detextro1.rpt.05111843 detextro1.rpt.05112054 detextro1.rpt.05112337 detextro1.rpt.05120029 detextro1.rpt.05120259 detextro1.rpt.05120557 detextro1.rpt.05120858 detextro1.rpt.05121000 detextro1.rpt.05121057 detextro1.rpt.05121150 detextro1.rpt.05121233 detextro1.rpt.05121330 detextro1.rpt.05121430 detextro1.rpt.05121534 detextro1.rpt.05121639 detextro1.rpt.05121741 detextr
Invalid command.

ftp> o1.rpt.05121838 detextro1.rpt.05122052 detextro1.rpt.05122341 detextro1.rpt.05130038 detextro1.rpt.05130249 detextro1.rpt.05130604 detextro1.rpt.05130904 detextro1.rpt.05131003 detextro1.rpt.05131057 detextro1.rpt.05131144 detextro1.rpt.05131245 detextro1.rpt.05131336 detextro1.rpt.05131437 detextro1.rpt.05131534 detextro1.rpt.05131636 detextro1.rpt.05131737 detextro1.rpt.05131850 detextro1.rpt.05132052 detextro1.rpt.05132349 detextro1.rpt.05140037 detextro1.rpt.05140355 detextro1.rpt.05140606 detextro1.rpt.05140853 detextro1.rpt.05140956 detextro1.rpt.05141047 detextro1.rpt.05141140 detextro1.rpt.05141237 detextro1.rpt.05141321 detextro1.rpt.05141419 detextro1.rpt.05141526 detextro1.rpt.05141628 detextro1.rpt.05141721 detextro1.rpt.05141820 detextro1.rpt.05142033 detextro1.rpt.05142216 detextro1.rpt.05151120 detextro1.rpt.05151226 detextro1.rpt.05151314 detextro1.rpt.05151411 detextro1.rpt.05151511 detextro1.rpt.05151609 detextro1.rpt.05151709 detextro1.rpt.05151811 detextro1.rpt.05152016 detextro1.rpt.05152322 detextro1.rpt.05160015 detextro1.rpt.05160233 detextro1.rpt.05160551 detextro1.rpt.05160838 detextro1.rpt.05160938 detextro1.rpt.05161034 detextro1.rpt.05161132 detextro1.rpt.05161423 detextro1.rpt.05161424 detextro1.rpt.05161429 detextro1.rpt.05161530 detextro1.rpt.05161635 detextro1.rpt.05161749 detextro1.rpt.05161902 detextro1.rpt.05162105 detextro1.rpt.05162344 detextro1.rpt.05170020 detextro1.rpt.05170308 detextro1.rpt.05170604 detextro1.rpt.05170839 detextro1.rpt.05170931 detextro1.rpt.05171026 detextro1.rpt.05171128 detextro1.rpt.05171223 detextro1.rpt.05171324 detextro1.rpt.05171418 detextro1.rpt.05171521 detextro1.rpt.05171631 detextro1.rpt.05171729 detextro1.rpt.05171826 detextro1.rpt.05172037 detextro1.rpt.05172337 detextro1.rpt.05180029 detextro1.rpt.05180305 detextro1.rpt.05180606 detextro1.rpt.05180854 detextro1.rpt.05180951 detextro1.rpt.05181045 detextro1.rpt.05181136 detextro1.rpt.05181237 detextro1.rpt.05181326 detextro1.rpt.05181430 dete
Invalid command.

ftp> xtro1.rpt.05181541 detextro1.rpt.05181635 detextro1.rpt.05181744 detextro1.rpt.05181838 detextro1.rpt.05182050 detextro1.rpt.05182341 detextro1.rpt.05190036 detextro1.rpt.05190310 detextro1.rpt.05190607 detextro1.rpt.05190853 detextro1.rpt.05190952 detextro1.rpt.05191053 detextro1.rpt.05191145 detextro1.rpt.05191232 detextro1.rpt.05191330 detextro1.rpt.05191431 detextro1.rpt.05191537 detextro1.rpt.05191643 detextro1.rpt.05191742 detextro1.rpt.05191855 detextro1.rpt.05192047 detextro1.rpt.05192339 detextro1.rpt.05200034 detextro1.rpt.05200254 detextro1.rpt.05200606 detextro1.rpt.05200857 detextro1.rpt.05201003 detextro1.rpt.05201058 detextro1.rpt.05201141 detextro1.rpt.05201250 detextro1.rpt.05201332 detextro1.rpt.05201431 detextro1.rpt.05201540 detextro1.rpt.05201638 detextro1.rpt.05201737 detextro1.rpt.05201846 detextro1.rpt.05202054 detextro1.rpt.05202352 detextro1.rpt.05210035 detextro1.rpt.05210315 detextro1.rpt.05210603 detextro1.rpt.05210850 detextro1.rpt.05210944 detextro1.rpt.05211043 detextro1.rpt.05211137 detextro1.rpt.05211232 detextro1.rpt.05211323 detextro1.rpt.05211419 detextro1.rpt.05211524 detextro1.rpt.05211625 detextro1.rpt.05211723 detextro1.rpt.05211822 detextro1.rpt.05212030 detextro1.rpt.05212216 detextro1.rpt.05220909 detextro1.rpt.05221026 detextro1.rpt.05221309 detextro1.rpt.05221317 detextro1.rpt.05221319 detextro1.rpt.05221411 detextro1.rpt.05221509 detextro1.rpt.05221609 detextro1.rpt.05221709 detextro1.rpt.05221812 detextro1.rpt.05222010 detextro1.rpt.05222319 detextro1.rpt.05230017 detextro1.rpt.05230237 detextro1.rpt.05230553 detextro1.rpt.05230843 detextro1.rpt.05230946 detextro1.rpt.05231036 detextro1.rpt.05231133 detextro1.rpt.05231228 detextro1.rpt.05231326 detextro1.rpt.05231424 detextro1.rpt.05231543 detextro1.rpt.05231642 detextro1.rpt.05231751 detextro1.rpt.05231900 detextro1.rpt.05232105 detextro1.rpt.05232331 detextro1.rpt.05240017 detextro1.rpt.05240303 detextro1.rpt.05240556 detextro1.rpt.05240842 detextro1.rpt.05240927 d
Invalid command.

ftp> etextro1.rpt.05241024 detextro1.rpt.05241134 detextro1.rpt.05241221 detextro1.rpt.05241320 detextro1.rpt.05241418 detextro1.rpt.05241527 detextro1.rpt.05241627 detextro1.rpt.05241725 detextro1.rpt.05241824 detextro1.rpt.05242045 detextro1.rpt.05242334 detextro1.rpt.05250025 detextro1.rpt.05250302 detextro1.rpt.05250604 detextro1.rpt.05250841 detextro1.rpt.05250949 detextro1.rpt.05251039 detextro1.rpt.05251129 detextro1.rpt.05251227 detextro1.rpt.05251326 detextro1.rpt.05251425 detextro1.rpt.05251531 detextro1.rpt.05251634 detextro1.rpt.05251734 detextro1.rpt.05251834 detextro1.rpt.05252046 detextro1.rpt.05252336 detextro1.rpt.05260029 detextro1.rpt.05260255 detextro1.rpt.05260558 detextro1.rpt.05260846 detextro1.rpt.05260956 detextro1.rpt.05261054 detextro1.rpt.05261139 detextro1.rpt.05261257 detextro1.rpt.05261332 detextro1.rpt.05261429 detextro1.rpt.05261537 detextro1.rpt.05261641 detextro1.rpt.05261739 detextro1.rpt.05261842 detextro1.rpt.05262045 detextro1.rpt.05262334 detextro1.rpt.05270028 detextro1.rpt.05270251 detextro1.rpt.05270601 detextro1.rpt.05270856 detextro1.rpt.05270952 detextro1.rpt.05271049 detextro1.rpt.05271145 detextro1.rpt.05271244 detextro1.rpt.05271334 detextro1.rpt.05271433 detextro1.rpt.05271535 detextro1.rpt.05271640 detextro1.rpt.05271741 detextro1.rpt.05271843 detextro1.rpt.05272048 detextro1.rpt.05272339 detextro1.rpt.05280033 detextro1.rpt.05280259 detextro1.rpt.05280557 detextro1.rpt.05280846 detextro1.rpt.05280942 detextro1.rpt.05281041 detextro1.rpt.05281137 detextro1.rpt.05281228 detextro1.rpt.05281322 detextro1.rpt.05281419 detextro1.rpt.05281523 detextro1.rpt.05281624 detextro1.rpt.05281723 detextro1.rpt.05281825 detextro1.rpt.05282026 detextro1.rpt.05282213 detextro1.rpt.05291136 detextro1.rpt.05291220 detextro1.rpt.05291313 detextro1.rpt.05291409 detextro1.rpt.05291512 detextro1.rpt.05291607 detextro1.rpt.05291707 detextro1.rpt.05291808 detextro1.rpt.05292014 detextro1.rpt.05292313 detextro1.rpt.05300011 detextro1.rpt.0530022
Invalid command.

ftp> 7 detextro1.rpt.05300548 detextro1.rpt.05300814 detextro1.rpt.05300909 detextro1.rpt.05301009 detextro1.rpt.05301111 detextro1.rpt.05301211 detextro1.rpt.05301312 detextro1.rpt.05301410 detextro1.rpt.05301510 detextro1.rpt.05301607 detextro1.rpt.05301707 detextro1.rpt.05301812 detextro1.rpt.05302010 detextro1.rpt.05302315 detextro1.rpt.05310229 detextro1.rpt.05310548 detextro1.rpt.05310831 detextro1.rpt.05310935 detextro1.rpt.05311034 detextro1.rpt.05311128 detextro1.rpt.05311224 detextro1.rpt.05311325 detextro1.rpt.05311428 detextro1.rpt.05311537 detextro1.rpt.05311639 detextro1.rpt.05311735 detextro1.rpt.05311846 detextro1.rpt.05312104 detextro1.rpt.05312336 detextro1.rpt.06010017 detextro1.rpt.06010301 detextro1.rpt.06010557 detextro1.rpt.06010826 detextro1.rpt.06010931 detextro1.rpt.06011028 detextro1.rpt.06011127 detextro1.rpt.06011227 detextro1.rpt.06011324 detextro1.rpt.06011423 detextro1.rpt.06011530 detextro1.rpt.06011626 detextro1.rpt.06011727 detextro1.rpt.06011830 detextro1.rpt.06012036 detextro1.rpt.06012334 detextro1.rpt.06020027 detextro1.rpt.06020255 detextro1.rpt.06020601 detextro1.rpt.06020921 detextro1.rpt.06021006 detextro1.rpt.06021050 detextro1.rpt.06021139
BYE
221-You have transferred 0 bytes in 0 files.
221-Total traffic for this session was 16161 bytes in 86 transfers.
221-Thank you for using the FTP service on ftp-out.
221 Goodbye.
```

Answer (score 1):

MGET is not part of the FTP protocol, so the limit (if any) is dependent on your FTP client, which must implement MGET as a series of GET commands.

It looks like you may be using the built-in command line FTP client that ships with Windows, in which case I would not be at all surprised if it has the bug you describe--that's probably the worst FTP client I've ever used.  I strongly suggest finding another FTP client--there are many available for Windows--even for the command line.